# Plotting a vertical line in R if a condition is met

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot vertical lines if a condition is met.

Example dataframe:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(
  X = c (1:5), 
  Y = c(8,15,3,1,4),
  indicator = c(1,0,1,0,0) 
)

example %>% ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Y)) + geom_line() + geom_vline(xintercept=X)
```

where X in the intercept is the value of X when the indicator value is 1. So in this case, I would only want the vertical lines for when the indicator value is 1. In this example, that would create a vertical line at X=1 and X=3. Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(
  X = c (1:5), 
  Y = c(8,15,3,1,4),
  indicator = c(1,0,1,0,0) 
)

example %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = X),
               data = example %>% filter(indicator == 1))

# OR using '.' instead of "example" in geom_vline
example %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = X),
               data = . %>% filter(indicator == 1))
```

Here is the resulting image.

[image]

**Note:** In the example above, the `data.frame` named `example` was used in the call to `geom_vline`, but this can be any other `data.frame` that contains the desired values to use as an intercept.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Minor tweak from above:

```
example %>% ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Y)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=X), data=. %>% filter(indicator == 1))
```

`data` can also be a function, so you don't need to hard code `example` in the `geom_vline` layer.  Since you are using dplyr anyway, it's easy to convert a pipe to a function by starting the pipeline with a dot.

Comment: Thank you for your addition, I'm adding this to my code :)

Comment: nice, also works with facets